# The limit of Kullback-Leibler divergence

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ -- i.i.d. sample. Suppose we have two models:

$$M_0: X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n \sim N(0, 1) \\
M_1: X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n \sim N(\theta, 1)$$

So we have two hypothesis: $H_0: \theta = 0, H_1: \theta \neq 0$. Let $AIC_0 = l_n(0), AIC_1 = l_n(\hat \theta) - 1$, where $\hat \theta = \bar X$. Here $l_n$ is logarithmic likelihood function. In order to decide, which hypothesis is most likely to be true, let us introduce the following function:

$$J_n = \begin{cases} 0,\quad \text{if  } AIC_0 > AIC_1 \\ 1,\quad \text{if  } AIC_1 \geq AIC_0 \end{cases}$$

a) how to find $\lim\limits_{n \to +\infty} P(J_n = 0~|~\theta = 0)$ and $\lim\limits_{n \to +\infty} P(J_n = 0~|~\theta \neq 0)$ ?

b) Let $p_{\theta}(x)$ is a density function of a random value $\sim N(\theta, 1)$. Let us define the following function:

$$\hat f_n(x) = \begin{cases} p_{0}(x), \quad \text{if  } J_n = 0 \\ p_{\hat \theta}(x), \quad \text{if  } J_n = 1 \end{cases}$$
How to show that $D_{KL}(p_{\theta}, \hat f_n) \to 0$ since $n \to +\infty$ for any $\theta$? Here $D_{KL}(f, g) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) \log\left(\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right) dx$ is Kullback–Leibler divergence.

I tried to solve this problems using definitions, but I didn't manage to do it. There must be some trick that wasn't noticed by me yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: At least a) looks pretty obvious, even without writing out formulas it seems clear that, since by the law of large numbers $\hat{\theta}_n\to\theta$, the limits should be respectively 1 and 0. Did you try to write it out yourself?